# Google Drive Video Player Start Time

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, google-api, google-drive-api

I have embedded a Google Drive video file into my website and I want to set a start time for the video.
Like embedding YouTube videos, is there a way of adding information at the end of the URL to set a start time?
Can I do this with javascript or google api some how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work just like youtube videos.

The start time html parameter: t={TIME}

{TIME} can be a couple of versions.

You can replace it with number of total seconds.  For example if you wanted to start a 10 minutes and 51 seconds, you would put https://drive.google.com/file/d/videoid/view?t=651s since (10 * 60) + 51 = 651

It also support hours,minutes,seconds format as well

https://drive.google.com/file/d/videoid/view?t=10m51s

https://drive.google.com/file/d/videoid/view?t=2h10m51s

Comment: Yuill , is it possible to set the end time also?