# Google Drive video iframe embed autostart and time

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api, google-drive-api

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848779/google-drive-video-player-start-time), I had been able to embed a video, autostart it, and even seek to a specific time.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/<file-id-here>/preview?autoplay=1&t=50s
```

While that link still works full screen for embedding, auto-start and time seek no longer are working. [This api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138204/7035457) works, but it seems to be a temporary signed link specific to each user, so it works locally, with jwplayer embedding it (for autostart/seek time functions), but anyone else I sent the page to with my generated link inserted into jwplayer, it returns 'error loading media: file could not be played'.

Is there anything else I can do, or am I basically screwed?

Comment: I tried it myself and it seems that this `autoplay=1` or `start=1` are no longer working. I also try it inside the `<iframe>` still it is not working. Changing the **preview** to **view** or **edit**, same result. Did not work. So what can I suggest you is try to contact the [Google Help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive) about this issue.

Comment: Yeah I've tried all the combinations of preview, view, edit with parameters. Shame, I'll have to post on that forum. Thank you.