# Google Drive video start time on iOS in Google Drive app

Tags: ios, youtube, google-drive-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to set a Google Drive video that opens in iOS via a url with a `googledrive://` protocol prefix to start at a specified time by adding a `t=15s` style argument like in web browsers?  (As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848779/google-drive-video-player-start-time), but for iOS/iPhone and when playing in the Google Drive app).

Comment: AFAIK, urls are platform independent whether it be iOS or Android. So https://drive.google.com/file/d/1234567890abcdefbg/view?t=60s when played should start in the 60 second mark.

Comment: This works in the iPhone browser (e.g. Safari), but I am asking about getting the `t=60s` part to work when opening in the Google Drive native iOS app.  Do you know how to make that work?  I add `googledrive://` as a prefix to the url in safari then it opens for me in the Google Drive app, but doesn't start to play at 60s…