# How to autoplay an embedded google drive video?

Tags: video, google-drive-api

I found how to start the google drive video at a given time [See stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848779/google-drive-video-player-start-time) but I did not found how to autoplay the video. Anyone can help?
More generally, I would like to know all the available options but I could not find the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed videos from Google drive to webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951504/how-to-embed-videos-from-google-drive-to-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in HTML5 then this should help.

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://source" type="video/mp4">
  Browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: don't forget a lot of the new caveats around auto-play videos depending on platform/browser that only allow it when muted, when in view, etc

Comment: this is a generic answer, not for google drive itself